# Javascript Remaining Characters without input

Tags: javascript, html, counter

Is it possible to have a pure Javascript text remaining counter that outputs the value in a `<span>` or `<p>` tag rather than an `input` field? I can only find Jquery solutions or ones that output in `input` fields.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but this isn't the right form to present it on Stack Overflow. You should ask a 'how do I' question and you can answer it yourself if you want to share your own solution

Comment: Re Peter's comment, more reading and the official position: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: You would probably want to pass the id of the `charsleft` span as a parameter to the function as well, otherwise it won't be possible to use it more than one time on each page.

Comment: Its not a question. You are allowed to ask only questions here. Yes, you can answer your own question.

Comment: have changed the format to make it a question and answered it below. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes it's possible .. actually I'm not sure.. what are you asking about?

Comment: @Esailija: read my answer below.

Comment: jQuery *is* pure JavaScript. Anything you can do with jQuery you can also do by writing the JavaScript yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have seen over the net that a lot of people are wanting a remaining characters counter that is pure Javascript and doesn't preview the number in an input box. I was messing around with JSFiddle lastnight and did a little work around and was able to get the remaining characters to show in other tags such as `<span>`. So I would just like to share this with everyone and hope it might come in handy.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="message" cols="20" rows="5" name="message" onKeyDown="textCounter('message','messagecount',100);" onKeyUp="textCounter('message','messagecount',100);"></textarea>
<span id="charsleft"></span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    function textCounter(textarea, countdown, maxlimit) {
        var textareaid = document.getElementById(textarea);
        if (textareaid.value.length > maxlimit)
          textareaid.value = textareaid.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
          document.getElementById('charsleft').innerHTML = '('+(maxlimit-textareaid.value.length)+' characters available)';
      }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    textCounter('message','messagecount',100);
</script>
```

Here is also a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLf85/1/)

Note: Should anyone want to contribute to the script to make it better, please feel free to do so. I am not an expert in Javascript so it most likely a more user friendly solution.

Kind Regards

Comment: `<canvas>` is what I would suggest!

Comment: You are making `textareaid` global. use `var textareaid`. Also I think, when max limit is reached , instead of substring each time, we can `return false` on `onKeyDown` event

Comment: @Jashwant: Have changed `textareaid` to `var textareaid` however not sure how to go about your second suggestion. If you would be able to edit my JSFiddle, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

something like the following should also work if you put jQuery on the page (and why wouldn't you :)):

```
$('#text-input-area').keyup(function(){
  $('#target-div').text(max_length-$(this).val().length + " characters remaining");
})
```

Comment: The method I used was pure Javascript as I don't see the point in loading a whole library just for a small function.

Comment: @Lodder aw come on, you'll use it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lodder's answer is perfect - except that I could not re-use it on the same page. I have tweaked the code to pass the name of the span, so it can be re-used on the same page.

```
<script>
 function textCounter(textarea, countdown, maxlimit, nameofspan) {
   var textareaid = document.getElementById(textarea);
    if (textareaid.value.length > maxlimit)
      textareaid.value = textareaid.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    else
      document.getElementById(nameofspan).innerHTML = '('+(maxlimit-textareaid.value.length)+' characters available)';
  }
</script>


<textarea id="message" cols="20" rows="5" name="message" onKeyDown="textCounter('message','messagecount',100,'messagespan');" onKeyUp="textCounter('message','messagecount',100,'messagespan');"></textarea>
<span id="messagespan"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    textCounter('message','messagecount',100,'messagespan');
</script>
```