# remaining symbols counter with the script

Tags: java, php, html, counter, symbols

Here is what I used to make it:

```
$maxbodylength = 3500;
    $body = trim($_POST["body"]);
if (strlen($_POST['body']) > $maxbodylength)

   print("<tr><td style='padding: 0px'><textarea maxlength=$maxbodylength name=body id=body cols=100 rows=20 style='border: 0px'>" . htmlspecialchars($arr["body"]) . "</textarea>  </td></tr>\n");
```

Currently I have managed to make posters to be allowed to type 3500 symbols. After making these 3500 they can no longer add more symbols to their post. How can I add a remaining symbols counter?

Comment: What have you tried? Do a google search for `javascript remaining characters counter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A remaining characters counter is easily implemented with JavaScript, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283244/javascript-remaining-characters-without-input#answer-11283308) for an example, or [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20remaining%20characters&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr) for a list of many more.